# Android constraint layout include another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I am having more of a conceptual question when it comes to `ConstraintLayout`. I want to re-use a layout inside my `ConstraintLayout`. But I ask myself a question that the `ConstraintLayout` aims at avoiding nesting of layouts and including a layout will decrease the `ConstraintLayout` performance. What is the best/ good practice to avoid nesting of layouts and at the same time re-use a layout so as to avoid code duplication?

Comment: It's totally ok to put a ConstraintLayout inside a LinearLayout/FrameLayout/ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<merge/>` tag to eliminate redundant view groups in your view hierarchy when including one layout within another.

Example:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <include layout="@layout/include_layout"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**include_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</merge>
```

**Result:**
[image]

In this case, without the `<merge/>` tag, you'll have two `ConstraintLayout` in the layout hierarchy.

[image]

**Reference:** https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Answer (score 1):

### Bottom Line

Don't be afraid of nesting `ConstraintLayout` as long as your View hierarchy doesn't grow too deep (<10). I'd consider it good practice to reuse and nest your layouts to avoid code duplication whenever it makes sense.

### Background

I quote from [the Android Developers page](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies):

> Additionally, if your app targets Android 7.0 (API level 24), it is likely that you can use a special layout editor to create a ConstraintLayout object instead of RelativeLayout. Doing so allows you to avoid many of the issues this section describes. The ConstraintLayout class offers similar layout control, but with much-improved performance. This class uses its own constraint-solving system to resolve relationships between views in a very different way from standard layouts.

[Optimizing Layout Hierarchies](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) from the developers page mentions that

> Deep layouts - Layouts with too much nesting are bad for performance. Consider using flatter layouts such as RelativeLayout or GridLayout to improve performance. The default maximum depth is 10

However, `ConstraintLayout` is not mentioned on this page explicitly and I might add that a depth of 10 nested layouts would almost surely result in a rather cluttered UI.

To add, in my professional experience as a software developer, I've never had performance issues with `ConstraintLayout` despite the fact that my team does use nested `ConstraintLayout`s regularly (with limited depth, I might add), most of the time encapsulated in custom View Components. That being sad, these events certainly don't occur excessively, since `ConstraintLayout` enables one to build UIs without excessive use of nesting.